# Angular-formly custom Validation on multiple fields on a repeat section

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I was trying to create a custom validator for angular-formly repeated section.

The form should be valid only if the sum of the percentage inputs is 100. So for example if repeat section has 2 fields 50 and 50 should be a valid option or 25 and 75 and so on.

While I was working on a [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/mekeca/edit?js,output) in order to do that I found out that the repeated model is not actually updated `onKeydown`. Therefore iterating though all the repeat section values and calculating their sum is not possible.

I also tried with `modelOptions: { updateOn: 'Keydown' }` with no success. It actually makes the validator not to get called at all.

---

**UPDATE**

I came up with the following solution from the matching fields example.
Unfortunately it appears that the example its self has a problem.

Play with the following JSbin and see that there are many cases where the validator gets called and returns true but the field/fields still remain red (indicating they have a problem).

Here is the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/weyoco/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: you might try: `modelOptions: {allowInvalid: true}`

Comment: @kentcdodds it still doesn't make the example work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies since I didn't had the time to get back on this one. It has an [open issue](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/issues) on GitHub for 2 months now. I fixed it temporary by using 7.1.2 version of angular-formly and just waiting for an update. The updated version of JSBin I have on the question should be working.

**UPDATE**

Since I had time and fixed this with repeat section (with a hacky way of course) I tough I should post it in case someone else is looking for this.

(note: the solution doesn't depend on formly version)

[Working JSBin](https://jsbin.com/loyoxi/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo while using `modelOptions: { updateOn: 'Keydown' }` the `Keydown`'s `k` should be `small case` instead of uppercase, after fixing typo its working as expected. Also the ngModelOptions accept all event name in small case like keydown, keyup, blur, focus, etc.

```
modelOptions: { updateOn: 'keydown' }
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](https://jsbin.com/davimalage/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: sorry but how is it working as expected? It's not updating the model and the validators do not fire.

Answer (score 0):

To create your own checks is best used reusable components, for example directive [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error).

Look at the example of [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/u50pmb37/).

```
<div ng-form="testForm" use-form-error="sumNot100" use-error-expression="input_1+input_2+input_3!=100">
  <label>Sum of all input must be 100</label>
  <br>
  <label>Input 1</label>
  <input ng-model="input_1" type="number" name="input_1">
  <label>Input 2</label>
  <input ng-model="input_2" type="number" name="input_2">
  <label>Input 3</label>
  <input ng-model="input_3" type="number" name="input_3">
  <div ng-messages="testForm.$error" class="errors">
    <div ng-message="sumNot100">
      Sum of all input not equal 100
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-disabled="testForm.$invalid">
    Submit
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry but how is this related with formly?

Comment: Since the `angular-formly` used `ngForm`, this solution can also be applied to the `angular-formly`. This is possible because the decision alters the **validity** of the form.

Comment: can you apply this solution to the repeat section of this jsbin though? https://jsbin.com/loyoxi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Sorry, but https://jsbin.com/darakekege/edit?js,output you specified - it does not work. And fix it I could not, not with loaded formly from rawgit.

Comment: strange.. I opened the jsbin on 2 different computers and its working fine.

Comment: I'm trying open it again. Can you create **jsfiddle**? I would be very grateful to you, you have raised an interesting topic.

Comment: @Jigar What error are you getting? It is working for me.